# "oauth.signpost.jetty.JettyOAuthConsumer" NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

Directly, i'v imported "signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar" to my project, and it has been aded to the "project build path" successfully, but when i tried to make an instance from JettyOAuthConsumer which is included in the jar,like this :

`JettyOAuthConsumer consumer = new JettyOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);`

p.s :- The jar is placed in a "libs" directory under my project directory,added to the "project build path", and a "Referenced Libraries" directory was auto-created including the jar reference.

I've received the following exception:-

```
11-04 17:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21732): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.jetty.JettyOAuthConsumer.
```

And this problem also occured with "signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar".

Wish to find a solution for this, thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder called `libs` under your project folder and add this library to that folder.

I was having the same problem with kSOAP library and this solved my problem...